# Extend polygons to match another polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, extend

I am struggling with this task :(
I have various layers, all having a common outer shape (see the blue polygon in the picture).

On of those polygons however, has a different shape.

I somehow need those polygons (the colorful ones) to extend, so they match the outline of my other polygon. The values do not really matter much, as long they are plausible relating to the neighboring cells.

I tried with a buffer, but it didn't really work. Manual reshaping is also no option, as I have hundreds of those areas.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would try these steps,

- Erase the Blue Polygons by the Yellow.
- Creates extents with Minimum     Bounding Geometry (Envelope).
- Append the Extents to the Yellow.